# Vue / Laravel - Dynamic multiple form saving data

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a dynamic form that successfully adds multiple field by a click of the button. My problem comes when saving the data in the database. I want to be able to save in the `employee_id` field the `id` of the `Auth::user`.

This is my current set of code. Should I use a different approach such as `for loop` instead of `foreach`?

**Component.vue**

```
           <tr v-for="(row, index) in rows" :key="row.id">
              <td><base-select
                :items="department_objectives"
                item-text="department_objective" 
                item-value="id" 
                label="Department Objectives"
              /></td>
              <td><v-textarea label="KPA" placeholder=" " class="mr-2" rows="1" outlined v-model="row.kpa" /></td>
              <td><v-textarea label="KPI" placeholder=" " class="mr-2" rows="1" outlined v-model="row.kpi" /></td>
              <td><v-text-field label="Weight" placeholder=" " class="mr-2" outlined  v-model="row.weight" /></td>
              <td><v-text-field label="Score" placeholder=" " class="mr-2" outlined :disabled="disabled" filled v-model="row.score" /></td>
              <td><a @click="removeElement(index);" style="cursor: pointer">Remove</a></td>
           </tr>

 addRow () {
        this.rows.push({
          kpa: '',
          kpi: '',
          weight: '',
          score: '',
          equal: '',
        });

 save () {
        axios
        .post('/api/employee-objective', { data: this.rows })
        .then(res => { console.log(res) })
        .catch(err => { console.log(err) });
      }
```

**Controller.php**

```
  public function store(Request $request) {
        foreach($request->data as $data) {
        $container = EmployeeObjective::updateOrCreate([
          'employee_id' => // insert ID
          'kpa_info' => $data['kpa'],
          'kpi_info' => $data['kpi'],
          'kpa_weight' => $data['weight'],
          'kpa_score_1' => $data['score'],
          'kpa_equal' => $data['equal'],
      ]);
      $container->save();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's fine using foreach as long all data you want is available like the key

to put the id of authenticated user in employee_id just put this one

```
Auth::id();
```

and put it above your code

```
use Auth;
```

Comment: I tried using both of these syntax and I'm having a post error 500.   `'employee_id' => $data[Auth::id()],` and   `'employee_id' => Auth::id(),`

Comment: It is still not working. Probably because it is not included inside the `v-for` syntax, but `type=hidden` is not working in vue.

Comment: No, v-for has no effect on that, your just assigning the id of the authenticated user inthe employee_id right ?

Comment: Yes sir. I wanted to input the `id` of authenticated user to every row that will be generated by `v-for`.

Comment: then what's the error ? I think I already gave you the solution

Comment: Hi I think I have seen where problem is. The `employee_id` is a foreign key and perhaps manually inserting data is not allowed.

Comment: It is not being inserted in the database, no error displayed in the console. It is being ignored by the `foreach` loop while others are successfully inserted. I tried changing `'kpa_info'` to `'employeed_id'` and it is indeed being ignored to be inserted since it is a foreign key column.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work, somehow this syntax works. Hopefully someone could enlighten me more about this.

**Controller.php**

```
    public function store(Request $request) 
    // This works
    foreach($request->rows as $data) {
      $test = new EmployeeObjective;
      $test->employee_id = $request->id;
      $test->kpa_info = $data['kpa'];
      $test->save();

    // This does not work
    foreach($request->rows as $data) {
      EmployeeObjective::updateOrCreate([
     'employee_id' => $request->id,
     'kpa_info' => $data['kpa'],
```

Now here is the tricky part. I saved the data from the `$store` to my local object and passed it during the save method.

**Component.vue**

```
created () {
  this.auth = this.$store.state.authUser.id
},

save () {
  axios.post('/api/employee-objective', { 
    rows: this.rows, 
    id: this.auth
  })
  .then(res => { console.log(res) })
  .catch(err => { console.log(err) });
}
```